# C# How to raise PostBack on Timer.Tick event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, timer

I use UpdatePanel with DataList element inside. I want to update the contents from DB every 10 secunds. I noticed that updating occures only after the postback. I did the code like

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DataList ID="lstComputers" runat="server" DataKeyField="ComputerID" DataSourceID="ComputersDataSource"
                    OnItemDataBound="lstComputers_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="lstComputers_ItemCommand">
                    <HeaderTemplate>

                    // Header data

                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>

                    // Item template

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>

                        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server">
                            <ProgressTemplate>
                                <img border="0" src="images/loading.gif" />
                            </ProgressTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdateProgress>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In code behind i tryed to use `RaisePostBackEvent` method but got Stack overflow exception...

```
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.RaisePostBackEvent(Timer1, "");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember that all your code-behind is executed on the server only. Therefore, if the Timer1_Tick() method is running, then your Timer *is* raising a PostBack.

The reason you get a StackOverflowException running that method is because it simply calls itself, infinitely. You need to place your update code in that method, not call it again recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the setTimeout() and setInterval() javascript functions.  This all needs to happen on the client, not the server side.

Answer (score -3):

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstComputers.DataBind();
}
```

Solved the problem with data reloading